# How to refer to other component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a simple confirmation overlay. I have an overlay component that will overlay any parent div. I want to be able to call the `confirm` function from any place in my app. The code below works, but I feel like I am going against the React philosophy. My main questions are:

- What is the alternative of using `getElementById('main')`? At the moment I want to overlay the same div, which I have given the 'main' id. This div is part of another React component. Can I use a ref in some way? Can I export this ref from the component I want to overlay and pass it to the `confirm` function?
- My main App Component also uses the `createRoot` function. Is it wrong to use it again?
- Am I using promises in the right way?
- How to optimize below code?

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { Overlay } from './Overlay'

interface IConfirm {
  text: string,
  destroy: () => void,
  resolve: (value: boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>) => void
}

export const Confirm = (props: IConfirm) => {
  return (
    <Overlay
      text={props.text}
      visible
    >
        <button onClick={() => {
          props.resolve(true)
          props.destroy()
        }}>Yes</button>
        <button onClick={() => {
          props.resolve(false)
          props.destroy()
        }}>No</button>
    </Overlay>
  )
}

export default function confirm (text: string) {
  const container = document.createElement('div')
  const main = document.getElementById('main')
  main!.appendChild(container)
  const root = createRoot(container)

  const destroy = () => {
    root.unmount()
    main?.removeChild(container)
  }

  const promise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
    root.render(<Confirm text={text} destroy={destroy} resolve={resolve} />)
  })

  return promise
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Better, but you're asking many questions in one post, so your title doesn't accurately reflect a single question. Optimization is too broad for SO.

Comment: This looks like a job for [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Seems like you should be passing a parent element to this component as a property, either explicitly (by node or ID), or implicitly (by whatever element it resides within).

Comment: My question is then how to pass this parent element. If I use getElementById it's easy, but it doesn't feel like the React way. Context seems a bit overkill. I want to be able to call the confirm function from any component in my app.